# How to match xPath using RegexBuddy?

Tags: xpath, regexbuddy

The expression `/bookstore/book[1]/title` should return `<title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>` but instead I get "The regular expression does not match..."

Here is my XML that I am testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

[image]

Comment: RegexBuddy is for developing/testing regular expressions, not doing XPath searches or filtering. In addition, you say "This should return", but you don't say anything about what "this" might be.

Comment: What does XPath in the drop-down allow me to do?

Comment: I removed my last comment, because RegexBuddy3 does include `XPath` in the drop-down list of languages on the `Use` tab. However, since you've posted no XML to use to try and match against, it's pretty hard to say what might be wrong. The `Help->Tools and Languages` menu item takes you to `Tools and Languages` in the help file, which has a whole section on `XQuery and XPath`.

Comment: My suspicion is that it takes very simple regular expressions and tries to convert them to their xPath equivalent; however, xPath is very limited syntax-wise. The documentation I pointed you to in my last comment should help.

Comment: I saw the documentation but still no luck. Under "Use" tab I see `fn:matches($input, "/bookstore/book[1]/title", "i")`, then I go back to "Test" tab and no matches.

Comment: You might have better luck asking in the RegexBuddy discussion forums. There's a tab in the app itself that will take you there directly from within RegexBuddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While RB can handle regular expressions for XPath, but it doesn't handle XPath paths.
For constructing/checking what's selected etc of XPath paths you'd need something like XPath Explorer, Firefox with Firebug+Firepath, or similar.